# Execute code if the app closes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

When I run the web application(Page_Load), I store an incomplete record in a SQL table where, after some data recollection from the user, update the record.
**If the app closes in the middle of this, can I execute a code where I can manipulate this record**??

I create the record in the Page_Load because I need to have a **table with real-time records** and know how many time take the user to complete the data capture.

Edit: The objective of this app is to calculate the repair time of a industrial machine. A repairman or engineer will insert data in the app while he is working with the machine.

Comment: There's no guaranteed reliable way to know when a user has stopped using a website.  Maybe they navigate away, maybe they close their browser, maybe they lose power, maybe they just get up and walk away from the keyboard, etc.  I'd recommend re-thinking the goal here.

Comment: What is **the app**?  The web browser, the server code?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But is more than a simple data capture. The objective of this app is to calculate the repair time of a industrial machine. A repairman or engineer will insert data in the app while he is working with the machine.

Comment: Web browser, sorry.

Comment: It's good to think in terms of leaving the application and its data in some acceptable state at the end of every single request. You could have a SQL record describing some interaction, and that record could indicate that the action is incomplete. But I wouldn't have any such thing as an "incomplete record."

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong words for the description. It's just a real-time table that show when a machine is not working because someone is repairing it. When the engineer finish the repair, the application delete the record in THIS table and insert a complete new record in another one. Looking for something like:

if(application.close) then SQLQUERY.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Global.ASAX to override the events.
-->https://forums.asp.net/t/1197922.aspx?Events+in+Global+ASAX

1. These are the events that can be included in the Globla.asax file for web application 1.    Application_Init : This event is fired when the application initializes for the first time.2.    Application_Start : This event fires for the first time when the asp.net web application starts3.    Application_BeginRequest : This event is fired for each http request that comes to the web application4.    Application_EndRequest : This event is fired for each end of the http request.5.    Application_AuthenticateRequest : This event is used to Authenticate a request. This is the event where you can check the user’s roles and rights.6.    Application_Error : This event is fired for all the unhandled exceptions in asp.net web application.Here we can capture the exception details and show to the end user7.    Application_End : This event is fired when the entire application is terminated i.e when certain time out is reached. Here we can clean up all the application memory allocated.8.    Session_Start : This event is fired when the user’s session is started for the first time. Here we can initialize the user specific information for that specific user in the asp.net web application.
2. Session_End : This event is fired when a specific user reaches his time out period.By default the session time out for a single user is 20 minutes.